# Unable to use .hasClass("active") method on dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is probably the biggest noob mistake, but on my navbar, I've set my dropdown link as active (displayed by the underline), and I have a function that checks when the link is clicked on, whether "dropdown" has the class "active," which it should, because I set it as so, and display an alert if this is the case. For some odd reason however, I can click on it all day long and nothing will happen - most likely because of the dropdown menu being triggered at the same time the link is clicked, but I don't see why that would be an issue.

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/XJ5FQMnJGQ).

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container"> 
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>                   
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">                    
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">                    
                <li><a href="#">1</a></li>                          
                <li class="dropdown active">    
                    <a href="2" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span>2</span><b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                    </ul><!-- END: "dropdown-menu" -->      
                </li><!-- END: "dropdown" -->                   
            </ul><!-- END: "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse" -->
        </div><!-- END: "container" -->
    </div><!-- END: "container" -->
</div><!-- END: "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" -->
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).on("click", "span",function(){
    if($("dropdown").hasClass("active")) {
        alert( $( this ).text() ); 
    }
});
```

Anyone know how to fix this function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The selector should be `.dropdown`, not `dropdown`.

http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

Comment: So, it was a noob mistake. Thank you so much - should've been more thorough with my view of the documentation, smh.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the selector with a '.' prefix, because this denotes a class.

> jQuery( ".class" )
>
> class: A class to search for. An element can have multiple classes; only one of them must match.